# reject invalid URLs from base64 encoder

Tags: node.js

I have a function in node for downloading a file and converting it to base64:

```
async function _conertImgToBase64(fileDet) {
    try {
        let downloadUrl = fileDet
        let tempUrl = appRoot + "/temp/" + "qn_image";
        let str = undefined
        let dowloadedFile = fs.createWriteStream(tempUrl);
        await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            http.get(downloadUrl, function (response) {
                console.log("response-fromfileserver",response.statusCode)
                if(response.statusCode==404){
                    
                }
                else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    dowloadedFile.on('finish', () => resolve());
                    response.pipe(dowloadedFile);
                }
            });
        })
        let imageAsBase64 = await fs.readFileSync(tempUrl, 'base64');

        if (imageAsBase64) {
            str = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageAsBase64
        }
        return str
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return false
    }
}
```

What i want is when response is 404. leave the function. I have an array of url .but every url is not working . i want only success url to convert base64 . I tried so many ways. can you help me .

Comment: just use `return false` as you used in catch function.

Comment: used but not response is get back to my client

Comment: use it with `reject()` , Because it's inside of promise.